# Need help in sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have following entries in my database table InOut

```
AutoId EmployeeId LogTime
1      1          12:24 PM
2      5          12:26 PM
3      1          12:27 PM
4      1          12:28 PM
5      5          12:31 PM
```

and so on...

No in my report i want to consider that first (Odd entry for the employee is In Time ) and Even entry for the same employee is Out Time.

In short i want following output

```
EmployeeId  InTime   OutTime
1           12:24 PM 12:27 PM
1           12:28 PM ---
5           12:26 PM 12:31 PM
```

so how can i achieve this output ??

Comment: That's a strange way to distinguish between in and out times.

Comment: see first,third,fifth entry (odd) is IN entry and second,forth,sixth is considered as OUT.

Comment: What constraints do you have? I.e. can an employee check IN/OUT several times a day? Can there be errors, i.e. can an employee forget to check out? Can an employee stay over night? Etc... In any case, it would be better to model your case as "sessions" (with in and out fields), rather than just unrelated timestamps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do what you want but if there is a mismatch between login and logout events you will have the wrong result. You should have some way to know if the event is a login or a logout event.

```
;with cte as
( 
  select EmployeeId,
         LogTime,
         row_number() over(partition by EmployeeId order by LogTime) as rn
  from @T
)
select C1.EmployeeId,
       C1.LogTime as InTime,
       C2.LogTime as OutTime
from cte as C1
  left outer join cte as C2
    on C1.EmployeeId = C2.EmployeeId and
       C1.rn + 1 = C2.rn
where C1.rn % 2 = 1
```